# Как получить ответ от system в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Пишу по linux. Выполняю команды bash таким образом:

```
system("команда");
```

Всё хорошо но как мне получать ответ? То есть результат выполнения команды, который выводится в консоль.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если пишите с Qt, то есть смысл пользоваться его функционалом - [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html)

```
const int NO_TIMEOUT = -1;

QProcess proc;
proc.start("/bin/bash", QStringList() << "echo \"Hello World\"");
proc.waitForFinished(NO_TIMEOUT);

QString proc_stdout = proc.readAllStandardOutput();
QString proc_stderr = proc.readAllStandardError();
```

[Еще кое-какой пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322739/how-to-execute-complex-linux-commands-in-qt)

Comment: Ниодна команда не работает. Делаю такую команду: mkdir /root/backup; tar -cvzf /root/backup/22.33.16-26.7.16.tar.gz /root/db/ Ответ в переменной proc_stderr такой: /bin/bash: mkdir /root/backup; tar -cvzf /root/backup/22.33.16-26.7.16.tar.gz /root/db/: ??? ?????? ????? ??? ????????

Comment: Выполняется ли команда в терминале?

Comment: да, выполняется

Comment: В отличии от system, QProcess запускает процесс с аргументами, а не выполняет строку (как командную строку). Т.е. программы можно запускать только по одной. proc.start("mkdir", QStringList()<<"/root/backup" ); ... proc.start("tar", QStringList()<<"-cvzf"<<"/root/backup/22.33.16-26.7.16.tar.gz" <<"/root/db/" ); ...

Comment: @Chorkov для такого кейса башу нужно [передать параметр "-c"](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=bash&category=1) и все будет хорошо.